# Pandas select index from grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll dataframe (grp):

```
key  ColA   ColB
2    23.4   33.4
3    43.2   45.3
4    12.3   90.3
5    11.2   77.3
```

grp is the result of a groupby operation performed earlier. Here 'key' is the index.

How can I create another dataframe with 'key' and 'ColA' as its elements? Right now, I cannot seem to select 'key'

Comment: Is `grp` really a dataframe, or is it just a groupby object?  Also, is `key` a column, or is it the index?

Comment: grp is a data frame, 'key' is index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). Assuming `grp` is the DataFrame as you have described:

```
res = grp['ColA'].reset_index()
# res is now a DataFrame with key and ColA as the columns
```

Comment: thanks, does this extend if I want to select ColB as well? What will the syntax look like then?

Comment: You can either use ``grp[['ColA', 'ColB']].reset_index()``, or simply ``grp.reset_index()`` if there are only two columns in total.